# Know when a line of code was added to a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, commit

I wonder how to know when a line of code was added to a GitHub repository.

I'm looking for commit hash so I could add a comment on this line of code (instead of opening an issue)

For example I have to know when this line

https://github.com/username/project/blob/master/path/to/file#L6

was added

So I could using 
https://github.com/username/project/commit/COMMIT_HASH

add a comment about this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly on GitHub, the button "blame" can give you the last commit having modified that line.
But not the *first* commit.

For that, you need to clone the repo and [use a `git log -L`](http://git%20log%20--pretty=short%20-u%20-L%20155,155:git-web--browse.sh):

```
 git log --pretty=short -u -L 6,6:afile.txt
```